# NetworkX seems to drop information in the graphml element declaration -- is there a way to recover that?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, graphml

Suppose a graphml file has nodes defined:

```
# foo.graphml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<graphml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns">
  <key id="x" for="node" attr.name="x" attr.type="string" />
  <graph>
    <node id="abc" type="x">
      <data key="x">y</data>
    </node>
  </graph>
</graphml>
```

And the following python3 code is run:

```
>>> import networkx
>>> graph = networkx.read_graphml('foo.graphml')
>>> nodes = list(graph.nodes(data=True))
>>> nodes
[('abc', {'x':'y'})]
```

Is there a way or manner to go about fetching the `type="x"` attribute from the element definition, or is that impossible/not part of graph-ml without some kind of kludge or conversion?